# How to edit/delete access database record in c#

Tags: c#

So i have a problem updating record in my database. My code runs without error, but the record is not updated. Here is the code:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            string sql = string.Format("update Alternatif set No ='" + textBox1.Text + "',Kecamatan='" + textBox2.Text + "',Kelurahan='" + textBox3.Text + "',Nama='" + textBox4.Text + "'where No ='" + textBox1.Text + "'");
            OleDbCommand perintah = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
            perintah.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data edited successfully");
            perintah.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data failed to edit");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have proven that the query works to update the record in access - you should consider capturing the int that is returned from ExecuteNonQuery and if it is 0, no records were updated

You should also consider having a good read of http://bobby-tables.com and promise yourself never to write an SQL again like you have there. It is prone to sql injection attack and is a massive security issue

---

Access is a file based database and typically when added to a visual studio there is a dev version of the file (the file as it was when selected for addition to the project) that is copied to the build directory every time a build is run. The app typically updates the build copy in the bin directory, not the dev copy outside the bin directory.

Developers then go looking in the dev copy and are surprised that no change was made- they're looking in the wrong file.

Or they go looking in the build copy, but after another build has been run and the edited db has been overwritten with a fresh, empty copy of the dev db. Search your project folder for all db and ensure you're inspecting the right one

You can stop the build process replacing the bin folder version of the file every time by finding the db in the solution explorer, getting properties on it and setting the Copy To Output Directory to something other than Copy Always. I personally use Copy If Newer

Comment: Ooppss!!  I'm sorry. I'm new to this so... I'll try it. Thank you very much!!